# Massive problems with dpkg and apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, dpkg, gconf, rsyslog

After several attempts to update, upgrade, reconfigure dpkg things and clean or install -f, I am quite desperate, since error messages persist, and I cannot quite find a solution. But let's focus on the first thing: When I do sudo dpkg --configure -a, then I get the following output:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.1) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
The user `syslog' is already a member of `tty'.
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 installed rsyslog package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up ufw (0.36-6) ...
dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 installed ufw package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-6ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 installed gconf2-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service-backend:
 gconf-service-backend depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service-backend (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service:
 gconf-service depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf-2-4:amd64:
 libgconf-2-4:amd64 depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf-2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not configured yet.
 gconf2 depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.6-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
 ufw
 grub-pc
 gconf2-common
 gconf-service-backend
 gconf-service
 libgconf-2-4:amd64
 gconf2
```

My system is currently Ubuntu 20.04. Things became bad when upgrading Ubuntu to the current version, as at some point, something froze.

Comment: I took a quick search of the internet, and did not see a lot of helpful debugging for what may have been a failed upgrade.  I think you are close to the point of some involved trouble shooting, or a reinstall of the OS.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for the reply. That does not sound too optimistic. How could this "involved trouble shooting" look like, for instance?

Comment: You could locate the script for rsyslog post-installation, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/rsyslog.postinst` modify the first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -x` and run `sudo dpkg --configure rsyslog` to see if any handy errors pop out.  The only error code I saw inside the script was `1`, not `10`.

Comment: you might be able to find something in the system logs first, in the `/var/log` directory you could check the dpkg log, and the system log.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have moved to ArchLinux by now. With this rolling release, everything works fine.